# Error at saving normal.dotm to network-storage with COM AddIn C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, com

I'm trying to modify and saving a normal.dotm template programmaticly with a Word COM AddIn in C#. I'm using the following code:

```
Template template = m_Application.NormalTemplate;
m_Application.CustomizationContext = template;
DoStuffWithTemplate();
template.Save();
```

This works absolutly fine... But, if the word template path is not at the default location on harddisk, but rather on a network disk, it will fail with the following exception:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A176B)
```

Works fine:

```
C:\Users\...\Templates\Normal.dotm
```

Throws Exception:

```
\\XYZ\Templates\Normal.dotm
```

I added the network path to the trusted locations inside the word trust center, but it still didn't work. I also run the application as administrator...

I'm using Word 2016, but the error occures also on Word 2010.

Thanks for your help!

edit:
Now I use the following work-around, but the changes are obviously only temporary now:

```
Template template = m_Application.NormalTemplate;
m_Application.CustomizationContext = template;
DoStuffWithTemplate();
if (template.FullName.StartsWith("\\\\"))
{
    if (!template.Saved)
    {
        template.Saved = true;
    }
}
else
{
    template.Save();
}
```

Comment: @GhostCat
Thanks. :)